# Bond strength of different isomers of an organic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry

Out of the following isomers of C7H7Cl containing benzene ring, i.e, out of

o-Chlorotoulene, m-Chlorotoulene, p-Chlorotoulene and Benzyl chloride, benzyl chloride has weakest C-Cl bond.

Why is it so?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Comment: Because the corresponding cation (or radical, for that matter) is the most stable of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a result of resonance structures. When a chemical entity (ion, radical etc.) has a lot resonance structures it is considered stable beacuase it allows the electrons to move around realtivily freely. If you remove the Cl from the benzyl chloride you can draw resonance structures by transfering the positive charge in the benzyl ring. Thus the positive charge can be delocalized making this structure more stable than the others that would be created from the chlorotoluenes.

Comment: Electrons do not move in resonance.

Comment: Other than that, the explanation is about right.

Comment: By electrons moving I meant that the charge can be delocalized. Is this incorrest?

Comment: The charge is delocalized all right, but not because electrons are moving. Instead, it is customary to say that electrons sit on the molecular orbitals, and thus each electron by itself is delocalized in such-and-such manner.